# How do you find the distribution of Y?

Tags: probability

the problem says that $X$~$N(μ,σ^2)$ and $ Y=1.2X+3.8$ And you need to find  the distribution of Y. I tried to apply the transformation of random variables.
$Fy(y)=p(Y<y)=p(1.2X+3.8<y)=p(x<(y-3.8)/1.2)=Fx((y-3.8)/1.2)$ But i dont know how to find Fx

Comment: Thanks, but you have to express $Fy=∫1/1.2fx((y−3.8)/1.2)dx$ becasue i think there is not way to integrate f(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the derivative of $F_X(x)$, it is the density function of $X$.

You can then use the result of your calculation to find the derivative of $F_Y(y)$ by applying the Chain Rule. That will give you the density function of $Y$.

You should find that $Y$ is normal mean $1.2\mu+3.8$ and variance $(1.2)^2\sigma^2$.

But perhaps it has already been proved that if $X$ is normal mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, then $aX+b$, where $a\ne 0$, is normal mean $a\mu+b$ and variance $a^2\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ has a normal distribution, then for any constants $a$ and $b$ (with $a \ne 0$), $aX + b$ has a normal distribution.  A normal distribution is characterized by its mean and variance...